# MS Access form field display format

Tags: ms-access, format, masking

We are working on an application using MS Acces 2003 and SQL Server 2005.
We are saving a fields that contain a text data for example `002215.28` but we want to display it on the screen in a special format for example like this `00 22 15.28`.

To do so on the Form Design toolbar and in the Format property box, we type a custom format
`00 00 00.##\.####`
but when we open the form screen the data appear like it was saved in the table

Please may you advise

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the column may be a text column, if so, you need say, @@ @@ @@\.@@

To format the control using number formats, you must first convert to number with, say, Val:

```
=Val([TextString])
```

Make sure that the control does not have the same name as the column, call it, say txtTextString.

There are various disadvantages to this, including:

- The control is not editable
- Val will return zero for alphas, giving 00 00 00..
- Val will return an error for Null values

The last two are not difficult to work around.

If the first is a problem, you may have to consider some VBA to fill the field.

Comment: Thanks Renou 
But when I am using the @ in the format of this field, it's affecting the value from the right to the left and not from the left to the right so If I have 001122 and the format is @@ @@ @@ teh result is 00 11 22 which is good 
but if I have 001122.33 the result will be 00112 2. 33 
we are working to find a good format 

Any help will be appreciated 

Thank you